# code in C of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 10?

Tags: c

I just started learning C. I am writing my code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    int i, s = 0;
    clrscr();
    for(i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++)
    {
        if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0))
        {
            printf("%d\n", &i);
            s = s + i;
        }
    }
    printf("sum is: %d\n", &s);
    getch();
}
```

But I am getting trouble in output, which is this:

[image: My output]

Comment: Why are you only running i to 5? Also print i, not the address of i. And download a better compiler!

Comment: Off-topic on StackOverflow. Use a good free software compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)...). Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with GCC). **Use the debugger** (e.g. [gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/)...)

Comment: BTW, your `i` is not initialized (only `s` is)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `i` is initialized in the `for`-loop

Comment: Thank you.. it solved my problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address operator `&` is unnecessary:

```
printf("%d\n", i);

printf("sum is: %d\n", s);
```

Comment: Not only unnecessary, but wrong. And a good compiler (with warnings enabled) would have caught that

Answer (score 1):

Correct your code from:

```
printf("%d\n", &i);
```

to:

```
printf("%d\n", i);
```

You do not need to use the `&` address operator.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%d\n",&i);` It should be `printf("%d\n",i);` and `&s` should be `s` Try below code...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
 int i,s=0;
 clrscr();
  for(i=1;i<=5;i++){

   if((i%3==0)||(i%5==0)){
     printf("%d\n",i);
     s=s+i;
   }
  }
 printf("sum is:%d\n",s);
 getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read how to use `printf` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

In short `printf` does not require address of the variable but value of it - which is
opposite to `scanf`.

Remove the `&` operator to use `printf` like:

```
printf("%d\n",i);
```

and

```
printf("sum is:%d\n",s);
```

See:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,s=0;
    clrscr();

    for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        if((i%3==0)||(i%5==0))
        {
            printf("%d\n",i);
            s=s+i;
        }
    }

    printf("sum is:%d\n",s);

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3                                                                                                                                            
5                                                                                                                                            
sum is:8
```

Other improvement  would be to comply with `C` standard and declare `main` as `int main(void)` instead of `void main()` and return a value from the program.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int i;
    printf("the multiples of 3 or 5 are :");
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        if ((i % 3 = 0) || (i % 5 = 0)) print("%d\n", i);
        else continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.